# OpenGL program giving a seg fault

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I'm learning OpenGL and for some reason my program to draw a triangle isn't working. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

int main()
{
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    if(!glfwOpenWindow(1080, 720, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glfwSetWindowTitle("Tutorial 01");

    glfwEnable(GLFW_STICKY_KEYS);

    do
    {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,
            3,
            GL_FLOAT,
            GL_FALSE,
            0,
            (void*)0
        );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers();
    }

    while(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) != GLFW_PRESS &&
          glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED));
}
```

Debugging log:

```
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:11
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:17
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:18
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:19
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:20
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:22
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:29
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:36
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In ?? () ()
At /home/mike/Programming/OpenGL Tutorials/Opening a window/main.cpp:36
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing it and seeing where it crashes?

Comment: Have you tried printing something to `stderr` at the start of the program, just to see if you can *read* stuff sent to `stderr`?

Comment: I did what you said DJ, it's a seg fault on line 36: glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID); now the question is why is this happening and how do I fix it.

Comment: And for the record @Nicol, I can write to stderr with no issue.

Comment: You're creating a Core context, where are your shaders?

Comment: @genpfault I don't do shaders until the next part of the tutorial which I don't really want to move onto until I figure out why this isn't working. According to the tutorial I should have a white triangle on the screen.

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

Comment: Did you try making a program that tries to do fewer things?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah. Just creating the window works fine. It's when I try and make the triangle that the seg fault comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Do an explicit version check after `glewInit()`:

```
if( !GLEW_VERSION_3_3 )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Insuffcient GL version!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This only makes sense if you want to ensure that a user has the correct version of glew installed (at runtime). At compile time It does not make sense to include that as a solution to the current problem (SIGSEGV main:36:glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID)).

Comment: EDITED to ADD: It is possible that @user768417 is not compiling against a version of glew that has support for it (< glew/GL v3.0).